# trying to create a circular buffer in C++ using struct

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct

I want to create a circular buffer using structs in c++. Basic implementation. I am having problems inserting elements to the buffer. Here is the code I wrote.

Here's my struct definition:

```
#define LENGTH_BUFFER 100
typedef struct {
  int buffer[LENGTH_BUFFER];
  int head;
  int tail;
} ringbuffer;


ringbuffer test;
```

Initialization to set the pointers to 0:

```
void RingBuffer_Init(ringbuffer temp)
{
  temp.head = 0;
  temp.tail = 0;
}
```

function for pushing data:

```
void RingBuffer_Push(int data,ringbuffer temp)
{
  temp.buffer[temp.head] = data;
  temp.head++;
}
```

here's is where I call the functions to initialize and push data

```
void main()
{
  RingBuffer_Init(test);
  RingBuffer_Push(25,test);

  cout << test.buffer[0]<<endl;
}
```

I cant seem to push data to my buffer. please help me out. it returns all zeroes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], as a guideline for new users here. Concerning your code, `LENGTH_BUFFER` is undefined, `typedef struct ...` is unnecessary in C++ and the whole isn't really formatted consistently, which makes reading and understanding difficult. Further, "I cant seem to" is an interpretation, but you are lacking the actual observations that lead you to this interpretation.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Please bare with me as this is my first time here. I have made modifications to the formatting. hope it clears it out.

Comment: Both RingBuffer_Init and RingBuffer_Push take the ringbuffer by value which means temp is a copy that you are modifying. Pass them by reference instead.

Comment: To move in C++ will also fix that problem because will work directly on the instance

Comment: @Ian4264 could you please elaborate this a little more. I am confused. the value gets passed to temp but why would it not be copied to the ringbuffer instance test?

Comment: `void RingBuffer_Push(int data,ringbuffer temp)` must be `void RingBuffer_Push(int data,ringbuffer & temp)` to avoid to get a copy of the ringbuffer

Comment: I like know how to do this but what I dont get is why can't I using a copy to push the data to my ringbuffer?

Comment: if you change a copy the original in main is unchanged so in main the ring is still empty

Comment: hey thanks for this. this really helps. I just have one more question. Why doesn't this behavior appear when we use standard data types in functions like an int or a char (pass by value) ?

Comment: the behavior is the same with builtin types. `void f(int i) { i++ ; /* here i values 2 */ } void g() { int i = 1 ; f(i); /* here i values 1, not 2 */ }`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

supposing *head* is the index where you place a new value, when you push a value `temp.head++;`must be replaced by `temp.head = (temp.head + 1) % BUFFER_LENGTH;` to manage the length of the buffer. You also have to move the *tail* when the buffer is full.

I do not understand why you push 1 value then write 5 values

You say you are in C++, so why do you write in C ? why you do not have a constructor and push/pop/top operation on ringbuffer ?

{edit add}

As you requested a very simple way to do in c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define LENGTH_BUFFER 4

// in c++ we use a struct when all members are public (by default all is public in a struct),
// but this is dangerous because all can be modified from outside without any protection,
// so I prefer to use a class with public/private parts

class RingBuffer {
  public:
    // The constructor, it replaces RingBuffer_Init,
    // The big advantage is you cannot miss to call the constructor
    RingBuffer();

    // it is not needed to have a destructor, the implicit destructor is ok

    // because it is an operation you do not have to give the ringbuffer in parameter
    void push(int data);

    // I had the print operation, it print following the order of insertion
    // to print doesn't change the instance, so I can say the operaiotn is 'const'
    void print() const;

  private:
    int buffer[LENGTH_BUFFER];
    int head; // index of the future value
    int tail; // index of the older inserted value, except if empty / head == index
};

// The buffer is initialized empty, head == tail
// I can initialize the indexes by any other valid
// value, this is not relevant
RingBuffer::RingBuffer() : head(0), tail(0) {
}

// push a new value, 
void RingBuffer::push(int data)
{
  buffer[head] = data;
  head = (head + 1) % LENGTH_BUFFER;

  if (head == tail)
    tail = (tail + 1) % LENGTH_BUFFER;
}

// print the content and indexes
void RingBuffer::print() const {
  for (int p = tail; p != head; p = (p + 1)  % LENGTH_BUFFER)
    cout << buffer[p] << ' ';
  cout << " (head=" << head << ", tail = " << tail << ')'  << endl;
}

int main()
{
  RingBuffer test;

  test.print();

  test.push(1);
  test.print();

  test.push(2);
  test.print();

  test.push(3);
  test.print();

  test.push(4);
  test.print();

  test.push(5);
  test.push(6);
  test.print();

  return 0;
}
```

I reduced the size of the buffer to rotate with few values.

The execution produces :

```
 (head=0, tail = 0)
1  (head=1, tail = 0)
1 2  (head=2, tail = 0)
1 2 3  (head=3, tail = 0)
2 3 4  (head=0, tail = 1)
4 5 6  (head=2, tail = 3)
```

As you can see in that implementation one entry is lost, it has the size 4 but manages only 3 values. I let you can change that, add top(), back(), pop() etc

Comment: Basically I just want to check if values are being pushed. I know it's going to overflow later on but for the purpose of implementation i pushed 1 value to check if it's being inserted.

Comment: I have modified the code. Please review it and let me know. thanks

Comment: you only changed `cout << test.buffer[0]<<endl;`no ?

Comment: Again, do you want to write in C or in C++ ?

Comment: yes also to your prior comment you said initialize the head and tail to 0 so I kind of seperated the functions to clear it out. i want to program using c++ .

Comment: in c++ all the behavior must be in the class, not outside it, so your functions must be changed to operations/methods

Comment: How do you suggest I do that?

Comment: @peterbrown I modified my answer

Comment: Perfect. that's the way to go as well. Thanks @bruno